# Django filebrowser settings

Tags: django, settings

Hopefully this will be an easy one for anyone with any Django experience.
I'm trying to get to grips with this framework and Python in general and have downloaded the filebrowser app.

It allows me to create folders OK, however it is unable to locate its css.

While looking at a page, I get the following in the console:

```
[20/Apr/2011 14:05:10] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11282
[20/Apr/2011 14:05:12] "GET /admin/filebrowser/browse/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14747
[20/Apr/2011 14:05:12] "GET /media/filebrowser/css/filebrowser.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2324
```

The third line appears in yellow as Django is unable to locate the css file.

Presumably I'm just missing / have an incorrect line in my settings.py file, but I'm not sure what I need to change.

Can anyone help?

These are the relavant (I think) lines from my settings:

```
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)`)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media/uploads/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = ''
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media/') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "grappelli/"
```

Any advice appreciated and apologies if this seems a little basic, I'm only just getting to grips with this really.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I can answer your question correctly.

If you are using the latest version of Django 1.3 and Django-Grapelli 2.3 then you need the latest version of Django-Filebrowser 3.3. This is becuse the old version of Filebrowser 3.2 and below, does not support static file, which is included by default in Django 1.3.

What you need to do is to svn the Filebrowser 3.3 from the branches to your python site-packages:

```
svn checkout http://django-filebrowser.googlecode.com/svn/branches/filebrowser_3_3/filebrowser filebrowser
```

Now you can run to get the filebrowser into your static folder:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [**`installation docs`**](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation):

Have you collected/symlinked/copied the files?

> If you’re not using staticfiles you
>   can either use a symlink from your
>   media-directory (given by MEDIA_ROOT
>   and MEDIA_URL) or copy the filebrowser
>   media-files to your media-directory.
>   Don’t forget to change the settings
>   accordingly.

edit:

It looks like the static files for django-filebrowser is stored:

```
filebrowser
|_ locale
|_ management
|_ media
|  |_ filebrowser
|     |_ css
|     |_ img
|     |_ js
|_ templates
|_ templatetags
```

This looks like the older setup of the django staticfiles app where media files were stored in the `media` directories of the apps (scroll to the bottom of these [**`docs`**](https://github.com/jezdez/django-staticfiles/blob/master/docs/settings.rst))

There are several ways to get around this, either by renaming that directory, copying/symlinking, or adding the directory to the `STATICFILES_DIR`

Comment: Hi,I've tried running python manage.py collectstatic and I get the following: 0 static files copied to '/home/dan/testsite/media/' (659 unmodified). Do you have a working example of a settings.py file that I could look at? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, Im away from my computer right now but I'll take a look an edit my post if no one else answers.

Answer (score 0):

for people working with older versions a workaround would be:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.finders import AppDirectoriesFinder
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import AppStaticStorage


class AppMediaStorage(AppStaticStorage):
    source_dir = 'media'

class MediaFinder(AppDirectoriesFinder):
    storage_class = AppMediaStorage
```

And then adding the MediaFinder function to STATICFILES_FINDERS